# Angular 4 - unable to "embed" a Flash .swf file

Tags: html, angular, flash

I have a very trivial AnimationComponent whose sole task is to display a .swf file, provided as Input. The HTML template follows:

```
<embed [src]="url" width="400" height="300" />
```

The Component code is as follows:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeResourceUrl, SafeUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
    selector: 'animation',
    templateUrl: './animation.component.html'
})

export class AnimationComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input()
    private code: string = '';
    private url: SafeResourceUrl;

    constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

ngOnInit() {
    let url = `/assets/SWF/${this.code}`;
    this.url = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
    }
}
```

When the Input parameter code is set to "Blob.swf the code generated in the browser is as follows:

```
<embed height="300" width="400" src="/assets/SWF/Blob.swf">
```

But an empty box is displayed and no animation exists. But this is where it gets weird. If I change the HTML template to:

```
<embed height="300" width="400" src="/assets/SWF/Blob.swf">
```

which the astute reader will see is EXACTLY the same as the code generated originally, the animation is displayed exactly as expected.

Can anyone think of any reason why the generated code, which is exactly as intended, fails to work and yet it works when the src is hard coded?

Comment: I have found a workaround. I have changed the template to:

Comment: If I change the template to
    <div innerHTML="html'></div>
And then build the entire embed HTML is the controller as a SafeHtml it all works.
Should I report this anomaly to the Angular team on Github?

Comment: what is the new value of the template you have changed the value to?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `attr` before `src` attribute. ex: `[attr.src]="..."`

@LimeyTX Share another solution on github:

```
<div [innerHTML]="html"></div>
```

```
 import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
 import { DomSanitizer, SafeResourceUrl, SafeUrl, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';
 @Component({
     selector: 'animation',
     templateUrl: './animation.component.html'
 })

export class AnimationComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input()
    private code: string = '';
    private url: SafeResourceUrl;
    private html: SafeHtml;

    constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        let url = `/assets/SWF/${this.code}`;
        let html = `<embed width="400" height="300" src="${url}" />`
        this.url = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
        this.html = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);
    }
}
```

[Link](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18184)